# Can an object call a method on its immediate descendant?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, inheritance

I have an inheritance hierarchy three deep : an abstract base class, from which I derive another abstract class, call it the intermediate class, from which will derive possibly a large variety of derived classes.

At one point, the base class calls a `this.GenerateXml()` method, implemented in the derived class, that returns nothing, but writes xml to a public property. At this point, I would like the intermediate class to do some stuff, without the base class or the derived class having to call a specific method on the intermediate class.

Is this possible in OO languages? Constructors call each other up the chain of inheritance. Can methods? Can an object call a method on its immediate descendant? The language in this case is C#

The obvious solution is to call a method, perhaps a same named method, from the derived class, using "base". This is less than ideal, because every derived class has to remember to make the call.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: The obvious solution is to call a method, perhaps a same named method, from the derived class, using "base". This is less than ideal, because every derived class has to remember to make the call.

Comment: I think you need to reconsider your design. What is wrong with `protected` methods?

Answer (score 7):

I think, what you're looking for is the [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). You define in one abstract class the general outline of what needs to be done by calling smaller, more fine-grained methods. One (or more) of these methods is abstract and must thus be implemented by inheriting classes.

```
abstract class Vehicle {
    public void drive() {
        startEngine();
        goForward();
        stopEngine();
    }

    protected abstract void goForward();

    private void startEngine() {
        ...
    }

    private void stopEngine() {
        ...
    }
}
```

All inheriting classes implement the `goForward()` method while only `drive()` is publicly visible. `Vehicle` thus defines how driving in general works while a `Car` or `Truck` implements the actual movement.

Your request seems to be a little more complex by using another inheritance layer. But, in general, I don't see a problem with another intermediate abstract class that passes the abstract method even further down, or even implements it using itself the template method pattern all over again.

Comment: Indeed, I have a template pattern, in that my abstract base class defines then calls abstract methods which are implemented by inheriting classes. But there is still no answer as to how I might walk the tree.

Comment: @user1585345 Okay, then what am I missing? You can have an abstract method in your base class, implemented in your intermediate class which in turn calls an abstract method in your derived class. Can you elaborate on what's missing in order to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

> ... the base class calls a this.GenerateXml() method, implemented in the derived class, that returns nothing, but writes xml to a public property. At this point, I would like the intermediate class to do some stuff, without the base class or the derived class having to call a specific method on the intermediate class.

When any of your classes calls "this.GenerateXml()", then your program will use the first implementation of that method that it can find, starting from the *current* class and working *upwards* through the Inheritance chain - Derived, Intermediate, Base.  So, what you're looking for will only work if the derived class *doesn't implement* GenerateXml.

The question is, what is this "stuff" that you want to do?  Is it something that might change from implementation to implementation?  If so, it should be defined in the base class as a protected, virtual (not abstract) method that your Intermediate class implements.  Of course, you will have to change the Base class to call this new method at the right time.

Comment: The work is generating an XML DOM. Some derived types will inherit directly from the base type, and their GenerateXML() can be called directly no problem. For the types that derive from the intermediate type, there appears to be no way of putting the shared work in the intermediate object and having the control pass "through" the intermediate object, without putting dedicated calls in the base, or in all the derived classes that inherit from the intermediate.